# Name this plant

Tags: vegetables, container-gardening

[image]

[image]

This was in a restaurant's kitchen garden on Whidbey Island, Washington. Can anyone tell me the common name for it?

Comment: Which plant? there are many in your picture...

Comment: Are you talking about the thing that travels out of the picture down below?  Or are you talking about the clump grass in the middle of your planter?  The other plants are iris and a morning glory type weed.  You have to take more pictures from different angles.

Comment: Looks like a Ruprecht to me.

Answer (score 5):

The (central) unfocused stalk in the foreground looks like an older flower head of a member of the genus **Allium** which includes garlic, onions, shallots etc. It may well be a garlic plant that was placed in the restaurant kitchen garden. The single flower heads of garlic (**Allium sativum**) forms at the top of a long stalk. This flower head (called an umbel) not only forms flowers with true seeds, but also can form groups of tiny bulbs (called bulbils). Your photo looks very much like a cluster of garlic bulbils which can be planted to grow small clones of the original plant. Additional links give more information.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allium

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garlic

http://greyduckgarlic.com/How_to_Grow_Garlic_from_Bulbils.html

Comment: Wow, great answer! I had no idea this is what wild garlic looks like.